# Can't run shell scripts

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I'm trying to run a script in my Terminal on OSX. I run it like this:
    $ script.sh input.txt output.txt
    -bash: Script.bash: command not found 
This script has worked before (with no changes to it) and it appears in the working directory when using the ls command. I don't know if this means anything but previously my script files had a .s logo on their filetype picture and now it is blank, like a .txt file (in Finder). Any help would be much appreciated! I tried using script.bash and the same thing happens. Thanks!

Comment: looks like the executable bit is missing. Set the executable bit and run using the path prefix `./script.sh input.txt output.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try "./COMMAND HERE"

or ". COMMAND HERE"

Comment: silly mistake on my part! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you need to have an explicit path if the script isn't in your $PATH

`./script.sh input.txt output.txt`

also you will want to make sure that the script is set as being executable

like:

`chmod 777 script.sh`

Comment: err 777 is a horrible mode. On a single user system it is probably fine, but on a multi-user system it is scary  755 or 750 or 700 a much better choice depending upon requirements.

Comment: Just use symbolic modes. `chmod +x` will serve and won't destroy the read and write modes.

Comment: yeah, absolutely..  should be +x, but I am not going to change it because it isn't technically wrong and am super annoyed at this moment by pedantic SO lurkers. so let the down votes fly.